# Cant make var available to meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

```
<template name="index">
  <textarea id="toSpeech" type="text">Type what you want to say!</textarea>
  <button>
    <span><a href="#" class="btn" id="openBtn">Sounds like</a></span>
  </button>
</template>

<template name="soundsLike">
  <div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="{{ reduced }}" style="zoom:0.60" width="99.6%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Template.index.events({
  // handle the form submission
  'click .btn': function(event) {
    Modal.show('soundsLike')
  }

});

Template.soundsLike.onRendered(function() {
  var src = $("#toSpeech").val();
  var replaced = src.replace(/ /g, '+');
  console.log(replaced);
});
```

I would like to pass the text in the textarea with #openBtn onclick. I'm using Template.soundsLike.onRenderer, however the variable is not available in the soundsLike modal template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `bootstrap-3-modal`, the [usage](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal/#usage) section gives you a way to transfer a data context to your modal:

```
Template.index.events({
  // handle the form submission
  'click .btn': function(event) {
    var src = $("#toSpeech").val();
    var replaced = src.replace(/ /g, '+');
    Modal.show('soundsLike', {replaced: replaced});
  }

});

Template.soundsLike.onRendered(function() {
  console.log(this.data.replaced);
});
```